# algorithm2e: reference to line numbers at beginning/end of while-loop

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithm2e

I want to reference to a line where a for/while-loop starts. However, with the normal `\label` command I cannot set a label in the respective line. How else can I reference to the beginning of, e.g., a while-loop? In particular for the example below, how can I create a reference for lines 2-6?

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

Reference to Lines \ref{alg:taskA}-\ref{alg:taskC}. How do I achieve a reference to lines 2-6?

\vspace{2em}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\KwData{some data}
\KwResult{some result}
initialization\;
\While{termination condition not satisfied}{
Do task A\label{alg:taskA}\\
Do task B\label{alg:taskB}\\
Do task C\label{alg:taskC}\\
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, simply add an new label after the closing `}` for the while loop: `\label{alg:endWhile}`  and add an label `\label{alg:startWhile}` for the start of the while loop ...

So with the following mwe

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}


\begin{document}

Reference to Lines~\ref{alg:taskA}--\ref{alg:taskC}. How do I achieve a reference to lines 2-6?

Like~\ref{alg:startWhile}--\ref{alg:endWhile}? % <===========================

\vspace{2em}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\KwData{some data}
\KwResult{some result}
initialization\;
\While{termination condition not satisfied}{\label{alg:startWhile} % <===========================
Do task A\label{alg:taskA}\\
Do task B\label{alg:taskB}\\
Do task C\label{alg:taskC}\\
}\label{alg:endWhile} % <===============================================
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: result]